# pdfgrep multiple files with different passwords

Tags: pdf, cygwin, pdfgrep

I am trying to grep strings in password protected PDFs (credit card statements). There are multiple files with different passwords. The [manpage(?)](https://pdfgrep.org/pdfgrep.html)  says --password=Value can be specified multiple times and each password would be tried against every pdf file to be grepped. But, I find it is only the last password that gets used.

```
pdfgrep -P "[0123][0-9] [JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrylgptv] [012][0-9].+[0-9,]+\.[0-9][0-9] *([cC][rR])?" --password=password1 --password=password2 *.pdf
```

Only password2 is being used and only those files are grepped. Obviously, other way round if password1 is last password given.

Couple of questions:

1. how to provide multiple passwords to pdfgrep?
2. any other simpler way of grepping (or getting a list of) credit card transactions from the monthly statements?

Not sure if it matters, I'm trying on cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

You may need this if it's not installed.
[Cygwin Package Summary for bash](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/bash.html)

You could put them on separate lines with a script.

```
#!/bin/bash

pdfgrep -P "[0123][0-9] [JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrylgptv] [012][0-9].+[0-9,]+\.[0-9][0-9] *([cC][rR])?" --password=password1 file1.pdf

pdfgrep -P "[0123][0-9] [JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrylgptv] [012][0-9].+[0-9,]+\.[0-9][0-9] *([cC][rR])?" --password=password2 file2.pdf

exit 0
```

Save it to: `pdfgrep_password.sh`
Change script mode to executable: `chmod +x pdfgrep_password.sh`
Run:  `./pdfgrep_password.sh`

If you need to `pdfgrep` many pdf files, and all of them have either password1 or password2, this will find out which password the file accepts, looping over all of them. Save as `pass_check.sh` etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.pdf; do

pdfgrep -Pq "[0123][0-9] [JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrylgptv] [012][0-9].+[0-9,]+\.[0-9][0-9] *([cC][rR])?" --password=pass "$file" 2> /dev/null

if [ $? == 2 ]; then
echo ""$file" DENIES #1."
else
echo ""$file" ACCEPTS #1."
fi

pdfgrep -Pq "[0123][0-9] [JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrylgptv] [012][0-9].+[0-9,]+\.[0-9][0-9] *([cC][rR])?" --password=word "$file" 2> /dev/null

if [ $? == 2 ]; then
echo ""$file" DENIES #2."
else
echo ""$file" ACCEPTS #2."
fi

done

exit 0
```

You can remove:

```
echo ""$file" DENIES...
else
```

Both lines, from both parts, for easier to read console output. I just used it as an `else` example.

Comment: I am doing this, but I am looking for why multipls passwords on the same command line are not all being considered.

Comment: @tpb261 It will work if you specify the file for each password. e.g. `--password=password1 --password=password2 file1.pdf file2.pdf`

Comment: I tried this. Doesn't work.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, that means `pdfgrep` only handles a single file at a time & cannot accept multiple arguments.  Listing each pdf in a script is the only way, really.  If you must avoid a script, you could end the first line with `;` (e.g. `command; command`) to run one after another, at terminal.